# Neo4j Cypher Match AND vs OR

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (childD:Decision)
MATCH (childD)-[mandatoryCriteriaVote1:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(mandatoryCriteriaId1:Criterion {deleted: false}) WHERE mandatoryCriteriaId1.id = 1 AND mandatoryCriteriaVote1.avgVotesWeight >= 1.0 WITH childD  
MATCH (childD)-[mandatoryCriteriaVote5:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(mandatoryCriteriaId5:Criterion {deleted: false}) WHERE mandatoryCriteriaId5.id = 5 AND mandatoryCriteriaVote5.avgVotesWeight >= 3.0 WITH childD  
RETURN childD
```

Right now the following part pf the query:

```
MATCH (childD)-[mandatoryCriteriaVote1:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(mandatoryCriteriaId1:Criterion {deleted: false}) WHERE mandatoryCriteriaId1.id = 1 AND mandatoryCriteriaVote1.avgVotesWeight >= 1.0 WITH childD  
MATCH (childD)-[mandatoryCriteriaVote5:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(mandatoryCriteriaId5:Criterion {deleted: false}) WHERE mandatoryCriteriaId5.id = 5 AND mandatoryCriteriaVote5.avgVotesWeight >= 3.0 WITH childD
```

works as a logical operation `AND`. This means that both conditions must be met for `childD` in order to be returned to the query result.

How to rewrite this query in order to work like logical `OR`?

I mean - return all `chilD` which meet any of the following conditions:

```
MATCH (childD)-[mandatoryCriteriaVote1:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(mandatoryCriteriaId1:Criterion {deleted: false}) WHERE mandatoryCriteriaId1.id = 1 AND mandatoryCriteriaVote1.avgVotesWeight >= 1.0 WITH childD
```

or

```
MATCH (childD)-[mandatoryCriteriaVote5:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(mandatoryCriteriaId5:Criterion {deleted: false}) WHERE mandatoryCriteriaId5.id = 5 AND mandatoryCriteriaVote5.avgVotesWeight >= 3.0 WITH childD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the same result by updating your as below:

```
MATCH (childD:Decision)
MATCH (childD)-[mandatoryCriteriaVote1:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(mandatoryCriteriaId1:Criterion {deleted: false}) 
WHERE (mandatoryCriteriaId1.id = 1 AND mandatoryCriteriaVote1.avgVotesWeight >= 1.0) 
OR (mandatoryCriteriaId1.id = 5 AND mandatoryCriteriaVote1.avgVotesWeight >= 3.0) 
RETURN childD
```